# Simulate mouse events

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse, virtual, mouseclick-event

I'm trying to simulate a mouse move using the following code: `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,150 ,150, 0, 0);`

It works fine, but the X and Y coordinates start from my current cursor position. Is there a way I can make them start at the upper left of my screen?

I'm working in a Windows form app using c#

If you have no clue of what I'm asking, I tried to draw it for you;[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN documents say that you can simply [set the position of a form's cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx).  Just do that, then send your mouseevent.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new Point(0, 0);
```

followed by your `mouse_event`, should do the trick.

Comment: This works perfectly, and actually looks so easy and logic haha, thanks Scott!

Comment: No problem.  Almost everything looks easy once you know about it. :-)